# Kendo UI for Angular - How to make PanelBar select based on the current route

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-panelbar

I'm trying to use PanelBar from KendoUI for my Angular app navigation.  Once you are on the page and use it for navigation it works just fine with router links.  However if I go directly to a link it doesn't work.  For example if I go to http://localhost:4200/licenses then the panel bar shows nothing selected, but if I go to just http://localhost:4200/ then click on the licenses portion it goes there and shows it selected.  How can I get it to show selected whenever I'm on that URL regardless of if it was navigated from in the page or from an external link?

Here is my navigation component code:

```
<kendo-panelbar>
  <kendo-panelbar-item title="Company Info" routerLink="/companydata"></kendo-panelbar-item>
  <kendo-panelbar-item title="Licenses" routerLink="/licenses"></kendo-panelbar-item>
  <kendo-panelbar-item title="Users" routerLink="/users"></kendo-panelbar-item>
  <kendo-panelbar-item title="Keynote Projects" routerLink="/knprojects" style="margin-bottom: 1em"></kendo-panelbar-item>
  <kendo-panelbar-item title="View Keynotes" expanded="true">
    <kendo-panelbar-item *ngFor="let project of Projects" title="{{ project.Name }}" routerLink="/knprojects/{{ project.ID }}"></kendo-panelbar-item>
  </kendo-panelbar-item>
</kendo-panelbar>
```

I also tried using the [selected] binding but when I did that it didn't show any selection regardless of where it came from...

Answer (score 0):

There is an Angular routerLinkActive propery to solve this issue. It is using with routerlink and it means add some class to property if router link is active.

If your active class is "active" just add it to your example:

```
<kendo-panelbar>
  <kendo-panelbar-item routerLinkActive = "active" title="Company Info" routerLink="/companydata"></kendo-panelbar-item>
  <kendo-panelbar-item routerLinkActive = "active" title="Licenses" routerLink="/licenses"></kendo-panelbar-item>
  <kendo-panelbar-item routerLinkActive = "active" title="Users" routerLink="/users"></kendo-panelbar-item>
  <kendo-panelbar-item routerLinkActive = "active" title="Keynote Projects" routerLink="/knprojects" style="margin-bottom: 1em"></kendo-panelbar-item>
  <kendo-panelbar-item routerLinkActive = "active" title="View Keynotes" expanded="true">
    <kendo-panelbar-item routerLinkActive = "active" *ngFor="let project of Projects" title="{{ project.Name }}" routerLink="/knprojects/{{ project.ID }}"></kendo-panelbar-item>
  </kendo-panelbar-item>
</kendo-panelbar>
```

Comment: hm. Ok that may work, but right now I haven't created a class for the selected state, it's just using whatever the Kendo default is.  Happen to know what that is?

Comment: Here is an example for that https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/layout/panelbar/routing/

Comment: Ok I thought I had tried that but I must have done something different this time because it worked with the selected binding.  I ended up putting the router in the TS file of the class as a property and then put in [selected]="router.url === '/companydata'" and other similar bindings and it's working now.  Not sure if that's the preferred way to get the route when you aren't going through all possible routes or not but it's working for me.  If you make that an answer I will accept it.

Comment: One additional gotcha that I did run into is if you have spaces in your route it will url encode them in the router.url property and therefore won't necessarily be the same when you compare them and could throw a wrench in things.  Just don't put spaces in your path :)

Comment: I didnt use kendo panelbar before but I researched for you. In my opinion, there is no any other way to do it. I can say you can use some other libraries for that panel/tabs.